# Hyperplane defined by dot product

Tags: linear-algebra

**Problem:**

> Let $v\in K^n, v\neq0$. Show that $vx=0$ defines a hyperplane in $K^n$.

The definition I'm working with: Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space of dimension $n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$. A hyperplane is a subspace of $V$ with dimension $n-1$.

---

Intuitively, for $x$ we have $n-1$ free parameters, since we can always choose the $n$th parameter in such a way that makes the dot product equal zero, but I haven't been able to show this formally so far.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Rank Nullity theorem?

Comment: @ThomasShelby Yes I am, but how would one apply it here?

Comment: Geometrically, you should consider the following. $v \cdot x = 0$ if and only if $v$ lies orthogonally on $x$. Can you see why this implies that this defines a hyperplane?

Comment: Define  $T:K^n\to K $ by $T (x)=v\cdot x$. What's  $\ker T $? What's the rank of $T $?

Comment: @Jonas Thank you for the comment, I can visualise what you said for low dimensions, however I'm not able to construct a formal proof from thereon.

Comment: @ThomasShelby Yes thanks, $ker T$ are the vectors $x$ and the rank of $T$ is $1$, so from the rank nullity theorem we get that $\dim \ker T=n-1$

Comment: HINT: Do you know Gram Schmidt?

Comment: @ThomasShelby Yes, I've edited the comment, otherwise it wouldn't make sense.

Comment: @Jonas No, I don't, but thank you for the help anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a constructive argument.  Let $e_1, \dots, e_n$ be a basis of $K^n$.  Since $v \neq 0$, at least one of the basis vectors $e_i$ must satisfy $v \cdot e_i \neq 0$.  Assume that $v \cdot e_n \neq 0$.  For each $i$ from $1$ to $n-1$, define
$$
    u_i = (v\cdot e_n) e_i - (v\cdot e_i) e_n
$$
It's easy to show that $u_1, u_2, \dots, u_{n-1}$ satisfy $v \cdot u_i = 0$.  It's less easy, but still pretty straightforward, to show that they are linearly independent.